# Casting objects

Tags: c++, casting, return

In my code i have sth like:

```
class A
{
 enum eType
 {
  A=0,
  B,
  C
 };
 virtual eType ReturnType()
 {
  return A;
 }
};

class B : A
{
 eType ReturnType()
 {
  return B;
 }
}

class C : A
{
 eType ReturnType()
 {
  return C;
 }
}
```

and I have many objects B and C class on my MFC CList. How I can write method like this

```
auto GetObjectFromList
{
 return object;
}
```

which return appropriate object. I mean when on list will be object B class, this method should return object class B with methods from B class and when it will be object class C this method should return object class C with class C methods? I tried with auto from C++11 but I can't do it right.

Comment: Why isn't returning an (pointer to possibly) A sufficient?

Comment: can you give an example of how you would want to use this function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean "class B : public A" right?

```
std::auto_ptr<A> GetObjectFromList()
{
    return std::auto_ptr<A>( new B ) ;  // you can new C if you want to return a C
}
```

Comment: Since OP seems to be using C++11, and `auto_ptr` is deprecated, maybe better to use `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you say that you have a collection of B and C. if you will not have an instance of A class, make it pure virtual by

virtual eType ReturnType() = 0;

Second, you need to make the inheritance by:

class A : **public** B

Then for the question, you will need to use dynamic_cast<> to see which instance is stored at the index you are looking for.